# retrieve onle variable from controller ionic AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

I have a view that shows a movie details 
I want to retrieve one row from SQLite and use it in the movies view, but I don't know how to do it, I did it like this ,I know it is a wrong way but it works for me

```
.controller('ChatDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams,$cordovaSQLite, $ionicPlatform , $ionicModal) {
    $scope.id=$stateParams.chatId;
  $scope.list=[];


    var query = "SELECT * FROM films WHERE id=?";
    $cordovaSQLite.execute( db, query, [$scope.id] )
    .then(function( response ) {

for ( var i=0; i < response.rows.length ; i++) {
            $scope.list.push({id: response.rows.item(i).id, name:  response.rows.item(i).name , Language: response.rows.item(i).Language, Genre: response.rows.item(i).Genre, Classification: response.rows.item(i).Classification, image: response.rows.item(i).image, trailer: response.rows.item(i).trailer, Story: response.rows.item(i).Story, rate: response.rows.item(i).rate, actor: response.rows.item(i).actor});

    }


    }, function( err ) {
        console.log(err);
    }
  )

})
```

I know that using list and for loop is wrong , I want a better way to get the response into separate variables like this : $scope.trailer = ... response details

this is also my movie view

```
<ion-view view-title="DHRUVA">
  <ion-content class="padding">

 <div class="list card" >


  <div class="item item-avatar" ng-repeat="item in list">
    <img src="img/dhruva.png">
 <h2"><b>{{item.name}}</b>    <img src="img/imdb.png"> {{item.rate}}</h2>
 <p>{{item.actor}}</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item item-image" ng-repeat="item in list">
    <img src="img/{{item.image}}" height="300" width="90">


  </br>


  <p><b>Story:</b> 
  {{item.Story}}  </p>

   <div class="row">
  <div class="col"> <p><b>Language:</b> {{item.Language}} </p></div>
    <div class="col"> <p><b>Classification:</b> {{item.Classification}} </p></div>
  <div class="col">   <p><b>Genre:</b> {{item.Genre}} </p></div>

</div>

<button class="button button-dark button-small" ng-click="modal.show()">
  Watch trailer 
</button> </br> </br> 
</div> 

</div>

 <div>

 </div>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I used ng-repeat and I sholudnt use it
how do I fix my controller and retrieve the variables without ng-repeat

thank you

Comment: why don't you simply do somthing like:  $scope.list={}; and then assign to it the properties from your query? for ( var i=0; i < response.rows.length ; i++) {
            $scope.list = {id: response.rows.item(i).id, name:  response.rows.item(i).name , Language: response.rows.item(i).Language, Genre: response.rows.item(i).Genre, Classification: response.rows.item(i).Classification, image: response.rows.item(i).image, trailer: response.rows.item(i).trailer, Story: response.rows.item(i).Story, rate: response.rows.item(i).rate, actor: response.rows.item(i).actor};

    }

Comment: so i put it as an answer..if it helped you .. can you rate it? .. thnx!

Answer (score 0):

why don't you simply do something like assign it as an object...something like:

```
  .controller('ChatDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams,$cordovaSQLite, $ionicPlatform , $ionicModal) {
    $scope.id=$stateParams.chatId;
  $scope.list={};


    var query = "SELECT * FROM films WHERE id=?";
    $cordovaSQLite.execute( db, query, [$scope.id] )
    .then(function( response ) {

for ( var i=0; i < response.rows.length ; i++) {
            $scope.list={id: response.rows.item(i).id, name:  response.rows.item(i).name , Language: response.rows.item(i).Language, Genre: response.rows.item(i).Genre, Classification: response.rows.item(i).Classification, image: response.rows.item(i).image, trailer: response.rows.item(i).trailer, Story: response.rows.item(i).Story, rate: response.rows.item(i).rate, actor: response.rows.item(i).actor};

    }


    }, function( err ) {
        console.log(err);
    }
  )

})
```